# VMWare perl toolkit download

Tags: perl, vmware-vsphere

I seem to be finding it far harder than is reasonable to find a recent copy of the VIPerl Toolkit to download.  There's a copy on sourceforge, but that's marked as beta and dated 2007.  There are hints at a newer version on the VMWare website, but pretty much every path I take through that website results in exceptions or other errors.   Help?

Comment: Ok, it turns out that switching browsers from Chrome to Firefox prevents the errors.  Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it by going to VMWare's site -> Support & Downloads -> All Downloads -> Pick Your Version -> Drivers & Tools -> Automation Tools and SDKs

I think they might have renamed it vSphere SDK for Perl for v4

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Zypher, that helped.

They haven't renamed it to Vsphere SDK for Perl - I think they have combined it in the list of SDKs that fall into the Vsphere SDK category.

Support And Downloads => SDKs and APIs => Vsphere SDK for Perl => under "Resources" tab - you will see "VI Perl Toolkit Download"

Be sure to be logged in while doing this - otherwise you'll have to login and do it all over again.

-- Saurabh